# trying to connect zongji to a remote database

Tags: mysql, node.js, remote-server

I am trying to separate my mysql server from my web application server.  I use node.js and zongji to listen for changes in the bin log on certain tables. When a change is made node pings the client letting them know there has been a change to the data.

When trying node.js and zongji on another server to connect with that same database I get and error

```
message: 'A slave with the same server_uuid/server_id as this slave has connected to the master; the first event \'mysql-1234-bin.000162\' at 79303225, the last event read from \'mysql-1234-bin.000162\' at 256, the last byte read from \'mysql-1234-bin.000162\' at 79303225.
```

Do I need to create a slave on the server to connect to remote mysql?
Does Zongji require that mysql be installed on the local machine?
How would I go about changing the server ID if that is the issue?

I the remote database that I am trying to connect to does have a master-master replication set up on the server.